# $_GET- how can i get name and type from the path?

Tags: php

in items.php

```
$filepath = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['filepath']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['type']);
echo $name,$type;
echo '<td><a target=\"_blank\" href="'.$filepath.'" title=\"\">'.$filepath.'</a> ';
```

error:

> Notice: Undefined index: name
>   Notice: Undefined index: type

result: `images/ch1.pdf?name=number?type=Memo`

i want to get the values from name and type.

Comment: try `var_dump($_GET)` and see the values of name & type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only use one question mark `?` and then seperate the variables with ampersands `&`

It should look like

```
images/ch1.pdf?name=number&type=Memo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass your parameters to your script using GET like `index.php?name=foo&type=bar`, you should be able to receive them in your PHP using `$_GET`, so your code looks like it should work.

I suggest removing `mysql_real_escape_string`. It may be screwing up your script.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is very basic security step, it doesn't screw the script. He is using `?` to separate variables instead of `&`, that's is the cause of problem.  I do recommend using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @Abhinav `mysql_real_escape_string` is secure when you are dealing with DB directly with it like in insert/update statement It is not intended for making html links. Which may generate problems. For that purpose urlencode/addslashes/htmlentities are already available,

Comment: You should use mysql_real_escape_string when performing MySQL queries. When using data from parameters you should probably decode the data, not escape it.